# Ruby gem Mysql2 return date type cannot be parsed

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I got the result in hash format: 
"date"=>#'<'Date: 4911851/2,0,2299161>

Anyone know how to parse this format?
I'd like to parse it in to a ruby Date object and do further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is still an timestamp object as far as I know. Just use it as it is inside an Date or DateTime to extract any data.

Alle the best.